# Old movie about a boy reading a book that is blank when he tries to flip ahead of the action

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

This is a kids' movie about kids; what I can remember from this pretty old movie is vague.

A boy reads a book, in that book is a scene where a man or a boy is riding a horse to a fountain.  They try to drink from it but it affects them, freezing the two. The boy who reads this book tries to skip a few pages or all of them to find out what happens to those two characters in the end, but all the pages are blank.

This movie may or may not contain (this may be another movie) some kids flying inside a wooden ... dragon?

From what I can remember, it is around 20 years old. It's not "The NeverEnding Story", even though my story is similar. It may be a TV series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is indeed a bit vague; why not check out the [guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they trigger any memories you can [edit] into the question?  For example, where did you see this?  How long ago?

Comment: And just how "old" is this? 1950s? 1980s? Early 2000s?

Comment: Wow.. First of all I am so glad that you people jumped to help me.. Thank you.. from what I can remember is around 20 years old... I've bumped a few time in this '84 "neverending story" movie but it's not this movie, even though my story is similar..it may be a TV series..

Comment: If you say it is not "the never ending story" do you mean the movie or all (the book, the '84 movie, the series '96 and 2001)? The 2001 series only bases loosely on the book/movie, what may explain the differences?

Comment: No clue of what this could be... Now I am also waiting for the answer because this seems like a very nice story!

Answer (score 3):

It's **Tales from the Neverending Story (2001)**

[IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0271308/)

You can watch the scene You just described here (although it's actually the same page repeated instead of blank pages):